Tensorflow 2 dimensional TensorArray
Inside a tf.function, I am implementing a 2D IIR filter. Assuming my IIR filter is of shape (dim1, dim2), I need the (dim1, dim2) most recent outputs to compute the next iteration.
The issue is that I need to modify the output matrix in place at every operation. I have tried with tf Variables, but they do not seem to carry over the gradient computation. I would like to have something that resembles the 2D TensorArray, or even easier, have the same functionality as a tensor in pytorch, where I can modify an index in place.
Here is a pseudocode snippet of how I currently do it, but it is very slow, as I create a tensor that has 1 only at the current location and multiply it with the current output to then add it to the output tensor.
@tf.function
def call(self, iir_input):

for i in range(iir_input.shape[0]):
    for j in range(iir_input.shape[1]):
        
        last_outputs = self._get_last_outputs() # gets the (dim1, dim2) last outputs from the output matrix

        output = (
           iir_input[i, j] 
           -tf.math.reduce_sum(self._iir_coeffs[:i+1, 1:j+1] * last_outputs[0:, 1:])
           -tf.math.reduce_sum(self._iir_coeffs[1:i+1, 0:j+1] * last_outputs[1:, 0:]) 
           +tf.math.reduce_sum(self._iir_coeffs[1:i+1, 1:j+1] * last_outputs[1:, 1:]) 
           )
           
        index_tensor = tf.cast(
            tf.scatter_nd(
                [[i, j]],
                (1.0,),
                (self._dim1, self._dim2),
        )

        self._output_matrix += output * index_tensor # can we replace this with a simple output_matrix[i, j] = output ?

return output_matrix

I tried an approach with tf.Variable, but there were issues with gradient propagation between iterations. The gradient should propagate between iterations as we have a recursive structure and it seems using the assign method does not pass the gradient.
Ideally I would want something like a 2D TensorArray, where I can store the output at [i, j] and then reuse it later iterations.
